# Differential of a rotated f(x, y) surface

Tags: surfaces, rotations, differential

I often hit this problem :

Consider a surface defined by the equation $z = f(x, y)$,

the differentials of this function are $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\mathrm{d}x$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\mathrm{d}y$.

But suppose that the surface is rotated by any space rotation $R$  :

the points of the surface are now $\left(\matrix{x'\\y'\\z'}\right) = R\left(\matrix{x\\ y\\ f(x, y)}\right)$.

What can be said about the differentials of the rotated surface?

I would like to write something about $\mathrm{d}x'$, $\mathrm{d}y'$ and $\mathrm{d}z'$ for the points on the rotated surface...

---

Edit :

I am looking for an expression of $\frac{\partial z'}{\partial x'}$ and $\frac{\partial z'}{\partial y'}$, which is the differential of the rotated surface as a function of $x'$ and $y'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your map $F(x,y) = R\left(\matrix{x\\ y\\ f(x, y)}\right)$ is the function composition $R \circ G$ where $R$ is a linear map (the rotation) and $G: (x,y) \mapsto (x,y,f(x,y))$.

Then you probably know what the derivative of a function composition is?

If not, the derivative of $F$ is $F^\prime=R^\prime \circ G^\prime$. As $R$ is linear, it is equal to its derivative. Hence $F^\prime = R \circ G^\prime$.
Can you figure out what is the derivative of $G$ which is a map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$?

You're right $\frac{\partial G}{\partial x} = \left(\matrix{1 \\ 0 \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}\right)$ so: $G^\prime(x,y) = \left(\matrix{1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}\right)$.

Finally:
$$F^\prime(x,y) = R \circ\left(\matrix{1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}\right)$$

**Now considering your additional question in the edit part.**

You have $(x^\prime, y^\prime, z^\prime)=F(x,y)$. You can rewrite the equality as:
$(x^\prime, y^\prime)=\varphi_1(x,y)$ and $z^\prime=\varphi_2(x,y)$.

Providing $\varphi_1$ is locally invertible at $(x,y)$, this is equivalent (locally) to $(x,y)=\varphi_1^{-1}(x^\prime, y^\prime)$ and $z^\prime=\varphi_2(x,y) = (\varphi_2 \circ \varphi_1^{-1})(x^\prime,y^\prime)$.

Using theorems on composition and inverse of derivatives you can then find $\frac{\partial z'}{\partial x'}$ and $\frac{\partial z'}{\partial y'}$.

Comment: I am not fully aware of composition for multiple variable functions. 
I would say that $F$ is a function of $x$ and $y$ but not $z$. But thanks for the clue.

Comment: I would say $\frac{\partial G}{\partial x} = \left(\matrix{1\\0\\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}\right)$

Comment: I understand that $\circ$ is like a matrix multiplication...

Comment: That's right. Composition of linear maps means multiplication of matrices.

Comment: Thank you for answering my edit. You could not knew, but what you propose doesn't really fit what I need. Because the function $f$ is not known, it is hard to write the function $\phi_1^{-1}$, which depends on $f^{-1}$. Wandering here and there I could find a solution to my problem : If $R$ is the rotation matrix and $Q$ its invert, $z'=R_{zx}x+R_{zy}y+R_{zz}f(x,y)$. Using $Q$ to express $x$ and $y$ as a function of $x'$, $y'$ and $z'$, one obtain a "12 terms" expression. Then I find $\frac{\partial z'}{\partial x'}$ and $\frac{\partial z'}{\partial y'}$ by differentiating along $x'$ and $y'$.

Answer (score 1):

Your surface $S$ initially has a representation of the form
$$F:\quad {\bf w}=(u,v)\mapsto {\bf x}=\bigl(u,v,f(u,v)\bigr)\ .$$
You then rotate $S$ in space by means of some rotation map $R$, resp. some orthogonal matrix $[R]$:
$${\bf x}\mapsto {\bf x}'=R{\bf x}\ .$$
The rotated surface $S':=R(S)$ then has a representation
$$G:=R\circ F:\quad {\bf w}\mapsto {\bf x}'=R\bigl(F({\bf w})\bigr)\ .$$
The chain rule then says that the derivative of $G$ is given by
$$dG({\bf w})=dR\bigl(F({\bf w})\bigr)\circ dF({\bf w}\bigr)\ .$$
Since $R$ is a linear map one has $dR({\bf x})=R$ for all ${\bf x}$, so that in terms of matrices we simply get
$$\bigl[dG({\bf w})\bigr]= [R]\>\left[\matrix{1&0\cr 0&1\cr f_{.1}(u,v)&f_{.2}(u,v)\cr}\right]\ .$$

Comment: On a general case, using your notations, we have : $\mathrm{d}G(u, v) = \left[\matrix{a & d \\ b& e\\c&f}\right]$, with $\frac{\partial G_x}{\partial u} = a$ and $\frac{\partial G_x}{\partial v} = d$ for example. If $b=d=0$, I could check on simple examples that $\frac{\partial G}{\partial x} = \frac{c}{a}$, and $\frac{\partial G}{\partial y} = \frac{f}{e}$. But I can not understand what is to be done if $b\neq 0$ and $d\neq 0$.

Comment: Working out this issue, I could find : $\frac{\partial G}{\partial x} = \frac{c. e - f. b}{a. e - d. b}$ and $\frac{\partial G}{\partial y} = \frac{c. d - f. a}{b.d - e.a}$. I have checked these formula on a sphere equation, it works well...